# Special uses of this syntax in PHP? (Triple 'Angle Brackets')

Tags: php, css, string, heredoc, brackets

Given the following code:

```
$myString = <<<script
   .
   .
   .
 script;
```

Thanks to the answers on the original version of this question, I understand <<< to be heredoc syntax, treated as double quotes without the need for escaping quotes.

Taking this a step further, how is this best exploited? Specifically, should this ease the strain of dealing with mixed quote strings containing code syntax?

i,e..

```
attribute="name-like string" attribute="property: 'value("value")';"
```

The thought is this may be useful (if implemented the way I am now guessing) especially when dealing with greater complexity and/or looking out for code injection. Again, looking for any scenarios where the heredoc for is particularly useful or exploitable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's Heredoc syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Its biggest virtue is that you don't have to worry about escaping quotes, since the string is not quote delimited.

Answer (score 3):

It's called heredoc syntax:

> A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: <<<. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.

[Read more here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: +1 for explaining the identifier here. Cleared up the syntax reading for me.

Answer (score 2):

It acts as a double qouted string, better to use double qoutes, easier to understand and easier to mantain in my eyes!

Comment: Niice.. It looked like a bitwise shift to me but figured it wasn't due to the extra "<". You learn something new everyday!

Comment: Indeed, but I find it easier to keep to one rule where I can, it makes it alot easier to write clean code, even though in some cases it can be useful, but it comes few and far between :)

Comment: I hear ya, consistency is the best.

Comment: heartily agree. thankfully this isn't *my* code =) I admit though, not escaping quotes in web code..seems like it could be pretty useful with strings of javascript and the like. Looking at this code, I don't think it was a bad practice as a search for <<<CSS produces very nice/relevant matches the way they've used it.

Comment: The Heredoc differs from double quoted strings in that you don't need to escape double quotes. And which variant  is “better to use” is highly debatable.